# How to loop over rows after .fetchAll Bookshelf js + knex js?

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a MySQL Database which I need to query from node.js

I am using bookshelf and knex for this.

I want to get the contents of a table - I have defined a table in my model.js file. I am attempting the query like this:

```
//select * from completedSentences;
Model.CompletedSentences.fetchAll().then(function (resData) {
        console.log(resData)
    })
```

I would like to know how to loop over resData because it should be multiple rows.

The output of the console looks like this: I dont see a list of rows I can loop over.. What am i missing?

```
CollectionBase {
  model:
   { [Function]
     NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
     NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
     NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor] },
  length: 1,
  models:
   [ ModelBase {
       attributes: [Object],
       _previousAttributes: [Object],
       changed: {},
       relations: {},
       cid: 'c4',
       id: 1 } ],
  _byId:
   { '1':
      ModelBase {
        attributes: [Object],
        _previousAttributes: [Object],
        changed: {},
        relations: {},
        cid: 'c4',
        id: 1 },
     c4:
      ModelBase {
        attributes: [Object],
        _previousAttributes: [Object],
        changed: {},
        relations: {},
        cid: 'c4',
        id: 1 } },
  _knex: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer (the documentation is very cryptic, hope this helps others)

```
new Model.CompletedSentences().fetchAll().then(function (resData) {
        _.each(resData.models, function (model) { //I am looping over models using underscore, you can use any loop
            console.log(model.attributes)
        })

    })
```

Comment: Wow I looked all over the documentation and could not find how to do this simple thing

Comment: As for me I found that result.lenght is not equal result.models.length (((

Answer (score 16):

```
Model.CompletedSentences.fetchAll().then(function (resData) {
        console.log(resData.serialize())
    })
```

output is in json format

http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-serialize

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and direct.

Comment: You the real MVP @RalleSaid

Answer (score 7):

The `Collection` class has a set of lodash methods for this.

You can use `collection.forEach` this way:

```
new Model.CompletedSentences().fetchAll().then(function (completedSentences) {
        completedSentences.forEach(function (model) {
            console.log(model.attributes)
        })    
    })
```

Check out the [docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-subsection-lodash-methods), there are many other useful methods for `Collection`.

Comment: Note that using lodash directly on Collection objects doesn't work (i.e., don't treat them like arrays and say `_.forEach(collection, cb)`. You have to call the methods on the collection: `collection.forEach(cb)`, as bookshelf turns that into `_.forEach(collection.models, cb)` under the covers for you).

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use lodash, you can do this:

```
new Model.CompletedSentences().fetchAll().then(function (resData) {
    resData.models.forEach( function (model) { 
        console.log(model.get('attribute');
        console.log(model.related('sth').get('attribute');
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

simply just console with it attributes.

```
console.log(resData.attributes);
```

you will get results Objects vise.

Answer (score -3):

Answer is simple, try this
`console.log(resData.toJSON())`